# Upper bound the Taylor series of the exponential function from $n=N+1$ for c>0, $N\to\infty$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, convergence-divergence, rate-of-convergence

Given some $c>0$ fixed, I am interested in upper bounding $$
e^{-c} \sum_{n=N+1}^\infty \frac{1}{n!} c^n \le 1-\frac{\Gamma(N+1,c)}{N!} \le 1-e^{-c} (1+\frac{c}{N+1})^N\le 1-e^{-c} (1+\frac{c}{N+1})^{N+1},
$$
where $\Gamma$ denotes the upper incomplete gamma function, and would like to know the convergence rate for $N\to\infty$.

So here comes my question:
Assume $c>0$ fixed. Which lower bounds of the form $$
\left(1+\frac{c}{N}\right)^N \geq l_c(N) \cdot e^c
$$
exist for $N\to\infty$? The faster $l_c(N)\to 1$, the better.

As discussed by Nilotpal below, $1-l_c(N)$ can be chosen to be of order $\frac{1}{N}$. But is this rate optimal? Or is there even a tighter way to upper bound the Taylor series from $n=N+1$ of the exponential function?

Comment: Show what you've tried to answer this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $c >0$ and $n \to \infty$, take the first two terms of the Laurent Series expansion about the point $n = \infty$ to get

$$
\left(1+\frac{c}{n}\right)^n > \left(1 - \frac{c^2}{2n}\right)e^c
$$

This converges as fast as the $\frac{1}{n}$ term.